# Constraint layout Overlapping Toolbar

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, drawerlayout

im having an issue with layout. I am trying to get the constraint layout to be placed underneath the toolbar. However, it decides it wants to overlap the toolbar. I have tried using app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" with no luck.

The toolbar is creating in another xml file and called in using include.

Activity below

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="XXXXXX"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<include
    android:id="@+id/test1234"
    layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/test1234">

**Bunch of constraints here etc**

**Bunch of buttons here**

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

[Here is an image of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n86EU.png)

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00WiX.png)

Edit

It is fine when shown in the design view of the android studio. However when opened on a phone or emulator it is still broken.

App still looks like the second image when emulated.

[With the fixes below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p9jIU.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same issue then i cracked it with this.
in your constraint layout, write this

```
     android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
```

Comment: So this seemed to work in the design view, but when i launch the app with an emulator the fix did not work :(

Comment: Your layout seems unfair to me. You have given match_parent to everything. Try changing them properly. use `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/" like this.
`

Answer (score 1):

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior
```

You're implying this attribute to the parent tag. You must add this to the ConstraintLayout or the main content of the drawer layout.

Comment: I have removed the attribute from the parent attribute. It has been positioned within the constraint layout. It is fine in the design view but when loaded onto the emulator it is still broken with the overlapping

Comment: Did you try wrapping your toolbar with AppBarLayout?

Comment: Hi, I have fixed it by pushing the constraint layout down by the size of the action bar.